# Caching Google JWT

Tags: oauth, jwt, google-authentication, google-oauth

I have a mobile app communicates with a server. For authentication in the mobile app, I'm using sign in with google. The sign in returns an accessToken which I send to my server and verify using `google-auth-library` as suggested here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

```js
import GoogleAuth from 'google-auth-library'
const auth = new GoogleAuth()
const client = new auth.OAuth2(MyClientId, '', '')

apiRoutes.use((req, res, next) => {
    // get the token from the request
    const token = req.token

    if (token) {
        // verify secret with google
        client.verifyIdToken(token, MyClientId, (err, payload) =>
            // proceed with the user authenticated
            ...
```

Is it necessary to make this call with every request that the user makes? Would it be good practice to do some sort of caching? Or to have my own implementation of JWT on my server that includes the google payload?

Answer (score 1):

No, the server should usually creates an account for the user once it validates the `access token`, saving the Google ID in the database along other user details (ID, email, name etc), and then returns an access token to the mobile application.

Once the latter (usually stored locally) expires, it can be [refreshed](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#offline) without prompting the user for permission.

Comment: And to clarify, when you say "then returns an access token", and "it can be refreshed", you are referring to the token that has been issued by my server, not the one issued by Google?